# How do I set phone numbers to be LTR in a RTL TextView with RTL characters

Tags: android

As you can see here, the phone number here is starting from the right to the left.

[image]

However, I want it to display it like this (Image here is edited):

[image: edited iamge]

This is the `TextView` displaying this message:

```xml
<TextView
    android:text="@string/smsSentTo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/smsSentTo"
    android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/chooseUsernameAndPickProfilePicture"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"/>
```

`@string/smsSentTo` (Arabic locale): (*looks like StackOverflow is displaying the {0} wrong, ignore that.*)

```
<string name="smsSentTo">تم إرسال رسالة SMS إلى {0}</string>
```

`@string/smsSentTo` (English locale):

```
<string name="smsSentTo">An SMS has been sent to {0}</string>
```

As you can see, I'm formatting the text using `MessageFormat`:

```java
String smsSentTo = MessageFormat.format(smsSentToTV.getText().toString(), phone);
smsSentToTV.setText(smsSentTo);
```

How can I get it to display these properly?

Comment: have you tried `textDirection` attribute?

Comment: @Pawel that would set the entire text to LTR

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution with a downside

```
String html = "<p>تم إرسال رسالة SMS إلي</p>" + "+961 01 234 567";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
```

The downside is that the HTML p tag prints a line afterwards separating the number into the next line. I tried to remove it with some HTML attributes or using tags other than p tag, but that didn't work

[image]

Hope this satisfies your need, or can give you even a clue.